# Adding Contact to particular group in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, contacts

We have a problem with adding contact to specific contact group in iOS 5. We've tested in Simulator and Device, but the result the same. Contact is added but not to "OUR" group.

In previous iOS versions everything is working OK! May be somebody has faced with such  problem?